# Rails nested forms & has_many :through model, don't save nested attributes until parent validated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm relatively new to rails, and have been attempting to set up nested forms for a has_many :through relationship. At the moment, I have these models-

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :building_photo_matchings
  has_many :photos, through: :building_photo_matchings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, reject_if: :all_blank
  validates :name, presence: true, length: {in: 1..100}, uniqueness: true
end

class BuildingPhotoMatching < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
  belongs_to :photo
end


class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :building_photo_matchings
  has_many :buildings, through: :building_photo_matchings
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :buildings, reject_if: :all_blank
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```

The nested forms work vice versa. I can create a building and upload many photos of it. I can upload a photo and identify the buildings in it.

But a problem arises here:  when I create a building, and upload many photos for it, the photos are still saved even when the building isn't validated.

Right now I'm handling this through the controllers, by destroying all the photos if the building is invalid. I don't think this is a good way of doing it though. Is there some way I can prevent the nested attributes from saving UNLESS the building is validated first?

```
  def new
    @building = Building.new
    4.times {@building.photos.build}
  end

  def create
    @building = Building.new(building) 
    if @building.invalid?
      for @photo in @building.photos
        @building.destroy!
      end
    end
    if @building.save
      redirect_to buildings_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) or [validates_presence_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_presence_of)?

Also a better way to do it in the controller would be to use before_save callback, but the model validation is a better way to go overall.